# What is the limit to the number of parameters you can have in Firebase Remote Configs for one project

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

Just started using the Firebase Remote Configs and could not find in the docs where it states the limit to the number of config parameters for one project. Anyone on the team know ?

Answer (score 6):

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters#limits_on_parameters_and_conditions) have been updated to include the limits.

> Within a Firebase project, you can have up to 2000 parameters, and up to 500 conditions. Parameter keys can be up to 256 characters long, must start with an underscore or English letter character (A-Z, a-z), and may also include numbers. The total length of parameter value strings within a project cannot exceed 800,000 characters.